# convert multiple data frame columns to numeric vector

Tags: r

I have this dataframe `df`:

```
C           S

F           7.6
O           8
T           9
```

I want to convert it to a `numeric vector` like this. Not **wide format**

```
F      O       T
7.6    8       9
```

I want to check with `class(df)` after and see `numeric`

How can I do that?

Comment: Please, I asked to numeric vector, not wide format!

Comment: Ah, I see the distinction, apologies ( ofc w your edit it is now abundantly clear as well :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setNames` to create a named vector :

```
vec <- setNames(df$S, df$C)
vec 
# F   O   T 
#7.6 8.0 9.0 

class(vec)
#[1] "numeric"
```